# Given n integers, find the m whose sum's absolute value is minimal

Tags: algorithm

I have *n* integers given; both positive and negative values are included. What is a good algorithm to find *m* integers from that list, such that that the absolute value of the sum of those *m* integers is the smallest possible?

Comment: I think that's what the 'professor' wants *you* to decide ... Is this homework?

Comment: This question is not stupid. It asks for the absolute value of the sum, not about the sum of the absolute values. For {-10,1,2,3,10} and m=2, the answer would be {-10,10}.

Comment: @Neal - Note, if you label it as homework, you stand at least a chance of someone helping you in some way. That is perhaps much less than you'd like, but greater than it stands now. :)

Comment: @pavium Absolutely not. I remember that professor's assignment was always not difficult to solve. Not like this one, I've spent 3 weeks on it, but my colleagues and I cannot get a good algorithm.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - Thanks for your advice. But trust me, this is not homework. I don't have any homework since I graduated.

Comment: @Lior Kogan - Aha, you got my question.

Comment: @Neal - New user, very specific word problem, with no code provided. If it's not homework, it's a terrific coincidence. Have you tried http://programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Jared: Algorithm questions are perfectly well on-topic here.

Comment: @Josh Caswell - Did I say they're not?

Comment: @Jared: It did sound like that was what you were saying with "Have you tried programmers.SE?"

Comment: @Josh Caswell - If I didn't believe it belonged here, I would have voted to move it/close it (which as you can see, is not the case). Simply, if there is a difficult question, http://programmers.stackexchance.com (or possibly one of the others, depending on application) is available. I don't know enough math to tell where it belongs. It's just a matter of whether Neal was aware there are other sites which may prove fruitful. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is NP-hard, since solving it efficiently would solve the [subset-sum decision problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) efficiently.

Given that, you're not going to find an efficient algorithm to solve it unless you believe that P=NP.

You can always come up with some heuristics to direct your search but in the worst case you'll have to check every subset of *m* integers.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the approximate algorithms for the subset-sum problem (that link is a decent start), you might be able to adapt some of them to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If "good" means "correct", then just try every possibility.  This will take you about `n choose m` time.  Very slow.  Unfortunately, this is the best you can do in general, because for any set of integers you can always add one more that is the negative of a sum of `m-1` other ones--and those others could all have the same sign, so you have no way to search.

If "good" means "fast and usually works okay", then there are various ways to proceed.  E.g.:

Suppose you can solve the problem for `m=2`, and suppose further you can solve it for both the positive and the negative answer (and then take the smaller of the two).  Now suppose you want to solve `m=4`.  Solve for `m=2`, then throw those two numbers out and solve again...should be obvious what to do next!  Now, what about `m=6`?

Now suppose you can solve the problem for `m=3` and `m=2`.  Think you can get a decent answer for `m=5`?

Finally, note that if you sort the numbers, you can solve for `m=2` in one pass, and for `m=3` you have an annoying quadratic search to do, but at least you can do it on only about a quarter of the list twice (the small halves of the positive and negative numbers) and look for a number of opposite sign to cancel.

Comment: kerr - “correct" idea was easy to get, but I tried to make it "fast and usually works okay", then I found it was not that easy because just as you said, m can change...